# How can I eliminate "linearScan by position" warnings?

Tags: chronicle-queue

I just upgraded from Chronicle Queue 4.6.109 to 5.16.16. Since the upgrade I noticed many warnings of the following form in all of our services that use Chronicle Queue:

> 2018-10-16 16:26:58,524 WARN  [main                     ] SCQIndexing          Took 256 us to linearScan by position from 379578902 to 379580588 = (0x169ff0ac-0x169fea16)=1686
>   2018-10-16 16:29:19,130 WARN  [main                     ] SCQIndexing           Took 315 us to linearScan by position from 411040047 to 411042086 = (0x18800126-0x187ff92f)=2039
>   2018-10-16 16:29:40,121 WARN  [main                     ] SCQIndexing          Took 73 us to linearScan by position from 415383606 to 415388071 = (0x18c251a7-0x18c24036)=4465
>   2018-10-16 16:34:03,655 WARN  [main                     ] SCQIndexing          Took 310 us to linearScan by position from 478146209 to 478150976 = (0x1c800140-0x1c7feea1)=4767
>   ...

Is this something to really worry about or just used for (internal) profiling? Is there anything I can change in my code to eliminate these warnings, i.e. reduce the scan time (except setting the property chronicle.queue.report.linear.scan.latency to false)?

Answer (score 1):

This is solved with 5.17.0. See https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/issues/526